# Issue with Accessing TensorFlow variable by name

Tags: python, tensorflow

In the following block, we create our weight variable `W` for each convo layer with the name `"hidden0/weights"` for the first convolutional layer of our network.

```
def convo_layer(num_in, num_out, width, prev, num, relu=True):
    with tf.variable_scope('hidden' + str(num)):
        initial = tf.truncated_normal([width, width, num_in, num_out], stddev=(2 / math.sqrt(width * width * num_in)))
        W = tf.Variable(initial, name = 'weights')
        initial = tf.constant(0.1, shape=[num_out])
        b = tf.Variable(initial, name='biases')
        if relu:
            h = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(prev, W, num) + b)
        else:
            h = conv2d(prev, W, num) + b
     return h
```

However, when we try to access this variable by name later in the code with

```
def get_vars(num):
    with tf.variable_scope('hidden' + str(num), reuse = True):
      tf.get_variable_scope().reuse_variables()
      weights = tf.get_variable('weights')
```

we get the following error message:

```
ValueError: Variable hidden0/weights does not exist, or was not 
created with tf.get_variable(). Did you mean to set reuse=None in VarScope?
```

We tried creating W with `tf.get_variable()` in the following way:

```
def convo_layer(num_in, num_out, width, prev, num, relu=True):
    with tf.variable_scope('hidden' + str(num)):
        initial = tf.truncated_normal([width, width, num_in, num_out], stddev=(2 / math.sqrt(width * width * num_in)))
        W = tf.get_variable("weights", initial)
        initial = tf.constant(0.1, shape=[num_out])
        b = tf.Variable(initial, name='biases')
        if relu:
            h = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(prev, W, num) + b)
        else:
            h = conv2d(prev, W, num) + b
        return h
```

However, in building our network we get the error

```
TypeError: Using a `tf.Tensor` as a Python `bool` is not allowed. Use 
`if t is not None:` instead of `if t:` to test if a tensor is 
defined, and use TensorFlow ops such as tf.cond to execute subgraphs 
conditioned on the value of a tensor.
```

Which leaves us stumped.

How should we go about creating and retrieving our weights?

Comment: How do you call the `convo_layer ` method?

Comment: @Nicolas We call `convo_layer` several times within a loop which lives in a method called `build_net`. We vary the arguments `num_in` and `num_out` depending on the structure of the desired network, and `num` is passed so that we can give the weights unique names.

Answer (score 0):

Variables created with tf.Variable are not visible to variable scopes, you need to create your variable with tf.get_variable.

The error you're seeing comes from "if relu" in your code, I think (it definitely comes from an if, and the stack trace should clearly point which one).